# What is CakePHP 3 home page? I can't redirect to that

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

I am developing a web page in `CakePHP 3` and I have a problem.

I have the view for the home page in `"src/Template/Pages/home.ctp"` and I create this function in the `PagesController.php`

```
public function home() 
{ //code...
}
```

I can enter to this page if I go to URL: http://example.com/Pages/home but if I go to http://example.com/ I not go to this page. And if I go to http://example.com/pages/home neither.

What is my mistake? I don't see it! I want to edit the "real" home page where I can go when I go to http://example.com

Comment: revert back all the changes and then hit the url:- http://domain.com/your_cakephp3_project_name/    And see what happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `config` folder in `routes.php` file:-

Change this

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
```

To

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']);
```

Comment: It works! There is no "secondary effect" of doing this?

Comment: Other functionality not effect with this. This is only point the homepage of website.